# Returning the new value with Object.assign with combinedLatestest in rxjs

Tags: angular, angular8, rxjs-pipeable-operators

So I am trying to add an additional property to the objects inside the itemAlarms observables array.
This is one object in the itemsAlarm array:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "healthType": "warning",
    "createdOn": "2020-03-11T05:47:14.38Z",
    "module": "00100",
    "version": "0",
    "index": 14
}
```

I am trying to transform it to add this additional property in each object of the array:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "itemsTypeId": "23",
    "healthType": "warning",
    "createdOn": "2020-03-11T05:47:14.38Z",
    "module": "00100",
    "version": "0",
    "index": 14
}
```

Both of these observables have an Id that are the same one and that is how I am finding the itemTypeId to merge it into the itemAlarms objects. 
items has id and itemsAlarms has itemId that have primary and fk relationship.

```
  this.items$ = this.itemsService.getEntities();
    this.itemsAlarms$ = this.itemsAlarmsEntityService.getEntities();

this.itemsAlarms$ = combineLatest([this.items$, this.itemsAlarms$]).pipe(
  map(([items, itemsAlarms]) => {
    itemsAlarms.forEach(alarm =>
      Object.assign({ itemId: items.find(item => item.id === alarm.Itemid).itemTypeId}, itemsAlarms)
    );
    return itemsAlarms;
  })
);
```

I thought the itemsAlarm would be the new transfered array, but it is the exact result of the original. I feel like I am doing something small wrong.

This is an example of what I am trying to do, but without zip because I keep getting messages it is deprecated:
http://jsbin.com/jiqofihoko/edit?js,console

Comment: turn `forEach` into `map`, and add `return Object.assign...`

Comment: So are the two input observable arrays or observables sequences?

Comment: I am out of scope when I do map(([items, itemsAlarms]) => itemAlarms), map(alarm =>  Object.assign({ itemId: items.find(item => item.id === alarm.Itemid).itemTypeId}, itemsAlarms) ) I get an error saying it can't reach items :( @Z.Bagley

Comment: observables sequences I believe. I am getting the data from an API and I get back an array of objects

Comment: If you could create a StackBlitz example it'd be easier to help. It's likely due to either `items` or `itemsAlarms` not being defined in your rxjs piped map. To ensure they are both available you can create an if statement and only run the code once both exist: `if (!!items && !!itemsAlarms) { itemsAlarms.forEach...}`